# Quantificador universal "cada"

Tags: sintaxe

Por que é considerado agramatical colocar um possessivo depois do quantificador "cada"?
Qual é a regra sintática que o impede?

Por exemplo:

> *Em cada seu livro ---> Em cada livro seu

Comment: não sei, mas é muito estranho para mim. Eu falaria: em cada livro seu...

Comment: Mas "em cada um dos seus" já soa bem de novo; que questão interessante...

Comment: E é o mesmo em inglês, não? *"In each his book" --> "In each (one) of his books".

Comment: @stafusa Or "in each his book" vs "in each book of his". This is more obvious in Spanish than in Portuguese because in Spanish they have a morphological distinction between the "atonic" possessive determiners and the tonic pronouns used post-nominally: *en cada su libro* is ungrammatical; you must say *en cada libro suyo*. I *think* the issue is how that determiner slot admits but one occupant, and so there isn't room for another. Doubling up two determiners in front instead of using an additional post-nominal tonic pronoun there just ***“sounds wrong to me”***, but I can't say “why”.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, the answer seems to be something in this direction. I hope someone can put it in a more rigorous manner.

Comment: @tchrist in fact Portuguese syntax allows for this use, simply because it sounds stunningly good. I suppose after enough use by poets, and the innate flexibility of the language allowing, it just becomes accepted as one possible form of syntax. However, if you were in school the teachers would probably reprehend you for pushing the limits of normal phrasing. (Your analyses was brilliant, doesn't come innately to me without picking up a grammar...)

Comment: Não sei a resposta, mas, a propósito de "em cada livro seu", eu diria que não é uma frase comum em português, exceto em casos bem específicos. Muitas vezes é um anglicismo, tradução literal de "in each of his books" – que seria melhor traduzido como "em *todos* os seus livros".

Answer (score 1):

Como disse, "cada" é um quantificador (universal):

> O quantificador é uma palavra que especifica um nome, **precedendo-o,** e que contribui para a construção do seu valor referencial, com informações sobre o número, a quantidade ou a parte das entidades designadas. [(ver mais)](https://www.jn.pt/artes/dossiers/portugues-atual/classes-de-palavras-o-quantificador-i-3605811.html)

Tal como o determinante, ele funciona como um **operador** no grupo nominal:

> (...)  o determinante individualiza o nome, especificando a sua referência com informação não quantitativa; o quantificador restringe a referência do nome com informação de natureza quantitativa.

e, portanto, partilha algumas propriedades com esta classe de palavras - nomeadamente o facto de anteceder o nome, o que até faz sentido, se pensarmos nesta lógica do *operador*.

No exemplo que deu, "livro" é o grupo nominal e o objeto que queremos quantificar, portanto "cada" deve antenceder "livro" - e não o pronome pessoal "seu" - de modo a que o quantificador possa "operar" sobre "livro". Por outro lado, ao pôr o quantificador antes do pronome, "seu", está a tornar isso o objeto que está a ser contado (ao contrário do pretendido).